# How to Delete duplicate in list of pairs

Tags: r

I have vector each element in this vector contain set of pairs,how i can delete the NULL values ,how i can delete the duplicate because (3,8) and (8,3) the same in my case

```
N
[[1]]
{<<NULL>>, (3, 8), (3, 9), (8,3)}

[[3]]
{<<NULL>>, (3, 2), (3, 8), (3, 9), (2,3)}
```

Comment: The structure of the vector is not clear.  Is it in `R` or in some other language?  Looks like a set of tuple from `python`

Comment: it is in R the vector contain elements ,each element set of pairs ,some thing like:                                                                                                               [[1]]
{<<NULL>>, (3, 8), (3, 9), (3, 10)}

Comment: Based on what you showed, the structure seems to be from python.  Please edit your post with the `dput` of the small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: y<-set(NULL,pair(1,2),pair(2,1),pair(3,4))                                                                     i want the vector  y to be :{(1,2),(3,4)}

Comment: Which libraries have the `pair` and `set` functions in R?

Comment: called "sets" package

Comment: your example `N` has indexes 1 and 3. How you created `N`? Using `sets` package, your special structure can be built. But you said above it is a vector of sets. But when building a vector using `c()` it builds a union of the sets but not a vector ... So are you sure this is a vector? `str(N)` will show you what type and structure `N` has ... (the type is important to find the correct manipulation functions and thus code ... )

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim N is a vector of mode "list", the indexes 1 and 3 are examples ,so first element of the vector N contain the set of pairs i showed above ,the third element as well

Comment: Thanks. I found the correct solution. Please upvote and accept ;) .

Answer (score 0):

We could remove the `NULL` by `unlist`ing the elements, then create the `set` based on the `pair`ing the alternate elements

```
library(sets)
N1 <- lapply(N, function(x) {x1 <- unlist(x)
   do.call(set,Map(pair, x1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], x1[c(FALSE, TRUE)])) })
N1
#[[1]]
#{(3, 8), (3, 9), (8, 3)}

#[[2]]
#{(2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 8), (3, 9)}
```

---

To remove the duplicates

```
lapply(N,function(x){ x1 <- unlist(x)
     l1 <- unique(lapply(split(x1, as.integer(gl(length(x1), 2,length(x1)))), sort))
     do.call(set, lapply(l1, function(x) pair(x[1], x[2])))
     })

#[[1]]
#{(3, 3), (8, 9)}

#[[2]]
#{(2, 3), (3, 8), (3, 9)}
```

#### data

```
N <- list(set(NULL, pair(3, 8), pair(3, 9), pair(8, 3)), 
        set(NULL, pair(3, 2), pair(3, 8), pair(3, 9), pair(2, 3)))
```

Comment: thank you for your help ,but i don't want to reorder the pairs,what i want that in the first set because there is (3,8) i wanna delete pair (8,3) and in the second element there is (2,3) so i wanna delete pair (3,2)

Comment: Isn't that deleted in the second set of codes.  The reorder is just to delete the duplicate elements

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the `sets` package.

Assuming N is a `vector` with the mode `"list"` as you say, you can do:

```
N <- list(set(NULL, pair(3, 8), pair(3, 9), pair(8, 3)), set(NULL, pair(3, 2), pair(3, 8), pair(3, 9), pair(2, 3)))
N <- as.vector(N, mode = "list")
N
## [[1]]
## {<<NULL>>, (3, 8), (3, 9), (8, 3)}

## [[2]]
## {<<NULL>>, (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 8), (3, 9)}
```

Remove the element `<<NULL>>` of each set:

```
N.cl <- sapply(N, function(s) {s[[NULL]] <- NULL; s})
N.cl

## [[1]]
## {(3, 8), (3, 9), (8, 3)}

## [[2]]
## {(2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 8), (3, 9)}
```

# ====================================================================

In the following, I just show what I tried before:

Assuming N is a `list`, you can do:

```
require(sets)

N <- list(set(NULL, pair(3, 8), pair(3, 9), pair(8, 3)), set(NULL, pair(3, 2), pair(3, 8), pair(3, 9), pair(2, 3)))

N
```

gives:

```
## [[1]]
## {<<NULL>>, (3, 8), (3, 9), (8, 3)}

## [[2]]
## {<<NULL>>, (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 8), (3, 9)}
```

Removing of the first set elements is done by:

```
N.cl <- lapply(N, function(s) {s[[NULL]] <- NULL; s})
N.cl
```

then gives:

```
## [[1]]
## {(3, 8), (3, 9), (8, 3)}

## [[2]]
## {(2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 8), (3, 9)}
```

An alternative method (which I found first) was:

```
# change the sets first to lists (the order in the set is kept):
N.as.lists <- lapply(N, as.list)

# remove first elements of those lists
N.as.lists.cleared <- lapply(N.as.lists, function(l) l[2:length(l)])

# change the lists to sets
N.cleared <- lapply(N.as.lists.cleared, as.set)

# inspect:
N.cleared

## [[1]]
## {(3, 8), (3, 9), (8, 3)}

## [[2]]
## {(2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 8), (3, 9)}
```

Comment: @arkan your code is really helpful , but i'm still have problem that some times the pairs shows duplicate for example :
{(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2)}

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
{(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 5), (5, 3)}

[[5]]
NULL